# Business rule fails to clear field value

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I followed [this tutorial](http://niiranen.eu/crm/2013/12/address-copy-button-business-rules-workflows/) to copy address field values. It works nicely but I got to thinking how can I make this better for my users..should have left well enough alone I know.

So I was thinking what if they selected the check box to copy the address1 fields by mistake out of habit. So I thought that it would be easy enough to just create a second business rule to clear the address2 fields.

Well the clear address rule is not working at all and yes it is activated. I mimicked the tutorial creating another custom field "clear address" then set my business rule that if that field has a value of true the set address2 fields value to "".

Doh it won't accept an empty value. Tried all sorts of gyrations no go. So I created another custom field (this is all in a development vm sandbox) called emptytext. It is a 1 char text field.

I then went back to my business rule and changed it to set the address2 fields to the emptytext field and that didn't work.

Ohh yes the field probably has to be on the form. So I put it on the form and hid it.

Now everything works but is this really the best way to set a text fields value back to empty?

Thank You

---

Edit:

As recommended by Jukka Niiranen [here](http://niiranen.eu/crm/2013/12/address-copy-button-business-rules-workflows/) anyone who reads this and would like to see Msoft add this feature should vote for it on connect. CRM 2013 – ability to set field value to NULL in Business Rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that's correct. Wherever you have this requirement you could create a field called "Blank" and always use this to set the value of any target fields you want to clear. You would need 1 'blanker' for each type of your business rules use so a text blanker, decimal blanker etc.  It only works if you put the blank field on the form, but you can choose to hide it by default.